# как сделать возможность проверки что слово не выйдет еще раз при начатие игры если слово уже использовалось

Tags: c#, readfile

Игра виселица

**подскажите пожалуйста как возможно это сделать что почитать чтоб возможность была сделать у меня была мысль что может сделать новый лист который так же будет считывать файл и после выигрыша перезаписывать этот лист удаля элемент который использовался правильно ли будет так сделать Добавить возможность сохранять уже сыгранные слова в файл, и при старте новой игры выбирать гарантированно новое слово. Например, если слово hello было уже отыграно (с любым результатом), при следующем запуске программы оно уже не будет выбрано. Слова с файла**

beer  brandy  whiskey  wine  tea  coffee  dancing

Comment: Ну вы сами решение описали — добавляйте сыгранные слова в файлик сыгранных слов и на старте программы фильтруйте.

Comment: @tym32167 затруднительно что надо все в 1 файле делать создавать новый нельзя а если считывать с 1 файла проект валиться ну и читать как я понял 1 файл в 2 разных словорях не есть хорошо

Comment: Почитайте про сериализацию тогда, чтобы хранить оба списка в одном файле.

Comment: Тебе не нужно никаких двух списков. Просто нужен 1 список слов и индекс начала текущего слова. При новой игре просто смещай индекс на следующее слово и запоминай этот индекс где-нибудь (например в файл).